# GeometryType undefined not supported

Tags: javascript, geolocation, sequelize.js, geojson

Mysql is returning Error: GeometryType undefined not supported when I'm trying to get the nearest users to a specified geometry latitude and longitude value. this is my query using sequelize

const location = sequelize.literal(`ST_GeomFromText('POINT(${long} ${lat})', 4326)`);

```
const nearestUsers = await Address.findAll({
            where: {
                location:[[sequelize.fn('ST_Distance_Sphere', sequelize.literal('geolocation'), location),'distance']],
                
                order: 'distance',
                limit: 4
            }
        })
```

and this is the address migration file

```js
'use strict';
/** @type {import('sequelize-cli').Migration} */
module.exports = {
  async up(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.createTable('addresses', {
      ...
      location: {
        type:Sequelize.GEOMETRY('POINT', 4326),
        allowNull:false
    },
   ...
    });
  },
  async down(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.dropTable('addresses');
  }
};
```

Please what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please show the model definition

Comment: Address.init({
  ...
    subUrb: DataTypes.STRING,
    street: DataTypes.STRING,
    houseNumber: DataTypes.STRING,
    location: {
        type: DataTypes.GEOMETRY('POINT', 4326),
        allowNull: false
    },

Comment: the location feild is where the error is coming from @Anatoly

Comment: Please show the generated SQL and the table definition from DB